# Symfony cache directory not automatically cleared

Tags: symfony

I have question about cache directory. I have symfony 3.4 in my server and after some time I found problem with empty space in my server. After investigation I found all my space spend in `/var/www/project/var/cache/dev` directory. My question, should cache directory cleared automatically after some memory limit? Or maybe fast solution add cache clear console command in cron ?

Comment: If it's a production server and a production application, you don't need to store **dev** cache

Comment: yes, production, but we use dev for analysed some case, what need to do with dev cache, some automatically cleared approach or manually ?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the caching function in Symfony,if you have memory limit..

add this code to your config_dev.yml and config.yml

```
twig:
    cache:  false
```